# How to set a select tag option by innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `select` options do not have `value` attribute

```
<select id='1'>
<option>Label1</option>
<option>Label2</option>
</select>
```

I know how I would set by value :

```
$("#1").val("whatever");
```

---

How can I set an option by innerHTML ?

I tried

```
$("#1").html("Label1");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would still set it with `.val()`:

```js
$("#1").val("Label2");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='1'>
<option>Label1</option>
<option>Label2</option>
</select>
```